# HDFS File Content View not visible from other Machines

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I can able to see content from machine which has hadoop server but i couldn't able to see the file content from other machines. In UI it was showing "couldn't preview the file".

Content should also visible from other machines.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What UI are you referring to? The `hadoop fs -ls` command should be your source of truth. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: I am referring Hadoop UI : http://localhost:50070

Comment: The namenode UI generally isn't useful for viewing files, especially large binary ones (Hadoop is not useful for small, plaintext files that can be loaded into a UI). `hadoop fs` commands should be preferred, such as `-cat` command mentioned in the docs